# How to play the levels 4 and 5 of the Factorio tutorial in multiplayer?

Tags: factorio

It explicitly says in Factorio, when you go to the "Single player -> New game -> Tutorial" interface, and I quote: "Levels 4 and 5 can be played in multiplayer".

We both completed the first three levels of the tutorial in solo player mode on separate computers with my friend.

Now when I go to "Multiplayer -> Host new game",  I do not see any way of creating a game with the tutorial level 4.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to advice received, I am able to confirm that you need to start the tutorial level 4 or 5 in solo player, then save the game, exit the game, start a new multiplayer saved game, pick the save created in the previous step, and wait for your friend to join.

I believe this could be fixed by the developers as users wanting to play the tutorial are new comers to the game and would not be aware of such tricks.